# gnuplot: Replace decimal point by another character

Tags: gnuplot, number-formatting

Using `gnuplot` v4.6.6:
To increase the available space for the actual graph I want to reduce the space required by the y-axis label to the bare minimum.

I'm now using: `set format y "%4.1s%c"`.
Which results in labels like `500.0k`. It would be nice if I could reduce this by one more character resulting in labels that look like this : `500k0`

However, I can't figure out how to get this. Can it be done, and if so: how?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: Here's an example graph of what I have now:
[image: example]
For this graph I use `set format y "%3.0s%c"` which is okay most of the time. But in some cases an extra decimal would be helpful.

Comment: Who not just make the graph bigger?

Comment: The graph is now 1280x320. Increasing it will mean that it won't fit on screen or paper and would need to be scaled down. Effectively destroying the resolution.

Comment: Don't use a pixel-based output format. Use a vector-based format instead. It's hard to recommend a format without knowing how you want to use the graph, but consider using e.g. the `pdfcairo` or `svg` terminals. For webpages also check out the `canvas` terminal.

Comment: `canvas` produces images 4x bigger than `png`. `svg` and `pngcairo` produces images 2x bigger. `pdfcairo` is almost 50x bigger. I don't see how changing the terminal is going to answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean by bigger in this context?

Comment: bigger as in kilobytes. The same graph `replot` using different terminals: `png` = 17kB; `svg` = 171kB (oops thats 10x; my bad); `canvas` = 45kB

Comment: Your question doesn't specify file size as an issue. And in general `pngcairo` looks better at the same size than `png`. The benefits of `pdf`, `svg` or `canvas` are that they can be scaled on screen or on paper without losing resolution or giving the blown-up pixel effect. A 1280x320 png won't look very nice printed on A4 or Letter paper. Additionally, you can zoom in on an SVG plot (and probably a canvas plot, but haven't tried that) on screen in your browser without sacrificing resolution.

Comment: In essence, my question was if it is possible to replace the decimal point on the y-axis tic labels by an appropriate character reflecting the magnitude (m, k, M, G). You changed the subject to graph size, then diverged to suggest other terminal types and now you drag in visual aestetics. None of those are part of the scope of the question and I don't like it that you now accuse me of supplying too little information. If you need additional, relevant, information to answer the original question please ask.

Comment: @Mausy5043: To summarise: If you need more space for your labels you have  the option to increase the canvas size, that was the whole point, and a legitimate alternative proposal. With something like `set terminal pdfcairo size 15in,7in`. BTW: have you tried the actual answer provided by @RolandSmith?

Comment: @Christoph : re your summary. I understand. But, the way I thought I asked the question was to increase the graph size by reducing the space used by the labels. I interpreted the answer as "buy a bigger monitor" :-) Re your BTW: yes I have tried it. I'm still considering if this solves my question as I think this may not scale when numbers in the 1e6 or 1e9 range need to be plotted.  I was hoping that I could get tic labels like `0M5` `1M0` `1M5` ... `2G3` etc. So, effectively three characters wide. Apologies if I came across slightly ticked :-)

Comment: @Mausy5043 What about `log10` scaling on the y-axis? See updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the decimal character:

```
set decimalsign 'k'
```

---

**Update**:

Or you could plot `log10(bits/s)`;

```
set yrange[0:9]
set ytics 1
plot 'data.d' using 1:(log10($2))
```

That would represent everything between 0 bits/s and 10^9 bits/s with *a single* digit on the y axis...